# Setting up SFML 1.6 with Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, sfml

After searching the internet for a guide on setting up SFML 1.6 with Xcode 4, i havent come across anything. I know that you cant use templates of SFML 1.6 with xcode 4. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, took me 5 days of fiddling to fix but it worked:

- followed everything in this guide : http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-osx.php

  - put sfml frameworks in /usr/local/lib/ **VERY IMPORTANT**
- downloaded xcode 3 dmg and installed in seperate location.
- made project from templates
- opened project in xcode 4 - doesn't compile
- went to Project -> build settings -> Framework Search Paths = /usr/local/lib

Xcode should compile fine now :)